# How to get IP Address of REST Consumer

Tags: php, rest

I would try to explain in diagrams

```
[REST SERVER] <--------> [JAVASCRIPT BASED WEBSITE]  <--------> [USER]
192.168.0.2              192.168.0.3                            192.168.0.123
```

How can I get the IP of the website that consumes the REST server instead of the USER's IP.

I tried using $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] and $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERRER'] but they both return the IP of the user.

Is it possible in the web? I'm using PHP for my REST server.

Comment: You cannot control what the user sends, no. You can try the REFERRER, but as you saw yourself it is completely dependent on what the users browser wants to send. This is a huge reason why so many websites use API keys (in order to identify where requests are coming from).

Comment: Does this JS website only host the JS files? I mean, it's not something like NodeJS, right? Basically your diagram isn't "correct". [See this paste](http://pastebin.com/MkrqWqFd)

Comment: Since you cannot do this securely, tell us why you are doing this. Maybe we can help you to an alternative.

Comment: You can try to check the origin headers by CORS, but ofc. it is not secure, and you will have a domain name instead of an ip address. You have to add API keys to each client and sign the requests for example with oauth.

Comment: @nl-x Well I'm trying to identify the REST consumer for security reasons. We are trying a pure javascript/html consumer.

Comment: And what are your "security" requirements and rules? By definition you have a public REST API which needs to be accessed by any random Joe Shmo. Define what "security" you need first.

Comment: @deceze I've implemented my own security, where in, the client is passing a hashed value of the concatenated Api-Id,Api-Key,Date and Time, and URL. Then everyting else is also passed in the header except for the Api-Key. now my only concern is that the api-key is still easy to capture if its in a javascript file. I need a way to secure this key, or at least get the genuine IP address of the consumer and not the user.

Comment: @PhilipBadilla you seem to not have a clear picture of that javascript is being run on the client side. So the consumer IS the user. You keep saying "javascript based website", but what you mean is just 'a dumb web server', with absolutely no notion of what javascript is. Javascript is just 'some file' for the web server. It does not do anything with it but serve it just like it serves HTML files and JPEG files. Javascript is ALWAYS downloaded first to the client, and then run locally at the client.

Comment: Again, take a step back first and define what exactly you are trying to prevent here. Sounds like you have a public website which needs to get data from your (public) REST API. I don't see anything that requires protection from anything to begin with. Clarify your scenario and what exactly you want to ***prevent*** in the first place. No technical details about keys or anything, just in plain English.

Comment: @nl-x yeah I do understand that part. I know that whenever a user browse a javascript based website. Everything else will come from their side. It's client side and I know that. That's why I'm trying to find a work around if not a standard practice.

Comment: @deceze The REST server provides resources of a restaurant, it could have multiple restaurant hosted on the server. I just want to secure data so that only applications with proper identification would be able to consume the REST.

Comment: That's a vague notion. The REST API will have to return data to anyone who asks, and the key will have to be publicly exposed to any and all users through Javascript. Even with a short-lived token system, anyone can get any token at any time to make a valid API request, and you will never be able to restrict API calls as coming from "your Javascript" or from Javascript at all. Again: **your API is public** and will give out data to anyone, anytime, **by necessity**.

Comment: @deceze I guess you are right. I'm wondering how did facebook managed to restrict the use of their API when using Javascript? Only registered domain for the application can use the javascript SDK.

Comment: Thanks for the help @deceze I think i would continue with the Api-Id + Key path. I'll just find a way to secure these values. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I'm not intimately familiar with Facebook's security model. I'm sure there's *a* solution, but for that you need to define your scenario a lot better. We're actually going completely off-topic from the original question here. I'd probably recommend you post a better thought-out question over on http://security.stackexchange.com to get the concept right. (And link that question here, out of interest.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll assume here that you mean the website is *hosted* on `192.168.0.3`. This means the *user* will be downloading the Javascript and HTML data from said server, and then execute it locally on `192.168.0.123`. That Javascript is then going to make remote calls to the REST service from that local IP.

You want to know how to get the IP of the server that hosted the Javascript/HTML files before the client downloaded them, presumably in a reliable fashion. And the answer is that this is not possible. Because your actual schema looks like this:

```
[JAVASCRIPT BASED WEBSITE] <--------> [USER]
192.168.0.3                           192.168.0.123
                                         ^
                                         |
[REST SERVER] <--------------------------+
192.168.0.2
```

Comment: I know from previous answers you are a clever guy but saying something is not possible... c'mon :)

Comment: Your answer only suggests a completely different workaround (probably the right answer, BTW). Getting the IP directly from the AJAX request literally is not possible.

Comment: @deceze that is exactly what I'm getting at. I'm just trying to find a work around. Because if my consumer is using just html/javascript it is possible for an attacker to get all the credentials by downloading the javascript.

Comment: I agree, deceze. @Philip - don't put credentials into JS at all :-S

Comment: @Philip "Attacker" who? "Attacker" what? A public REST API is by definition public. What does an "attack" look like here?

Comment: @PhilipBadilla What credentials? And how does identifying the IP address of the javascript server prevent this?

Comment: @deceze I just want to make the REST api not "that" public. Meaning only applications with credentials can get/update resources. I have a table of list of API-Key that are used by applications for security reasons. I'm just trying to avoid spoofing.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot do this securely. You will have to make the javascript pass this to the server. And since javascript is run client side, this can be spoofed.

And even then, javascript does not have native functions to get you the IP address of the website. It can give you the domain name though. And then in, for example, PHP you can resolve this domain name to an IP address. Or have the javascript based web server give its IP address directly along. For example with the help of PHP, you can do in javascript: `var myIP = '<?php echo $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']; ?>';`

Answer (score 1):

As a sidenote, the `Origin` header (can be spoofed) is ment for this purpose but a secure workaround would be some kind of handshake between JS server and REST server.

Javascript based webpage requests a token code via serverside, you put this token code into the javascript and send it to the rest server.

The rest server verifies the token code and then you know for sure where the javascript resides.

This is the only method of verifying the origin, it is not possible via plain IP addresses.

Comment: Why bother with the origin header? Have the REST server give the javascript based server a token, when it is generating the javascript, so the token can be included in the javascript.

Comment: @nl-x That's what I suggest, I didnt write that clearly. I don't bother about the Origin header, it's just a sidenote.